# Why does defaultdict register keys without assignments

Tags: python, defaultdict

In python 3, if you define a `defaultdict`, trigger the default values to be returned with a non-existent key, then that key will be automatically put into the dictionary?? This:

```py
foo = defaultdict(int)
1 in foo # False
foo[1]   # 0
1 in foo # True????
```

This seems erroneous to me. I feel like the purpose of `defaultdict` is to allow the user to get a default value without putting that key in the dictionary. Why did the language developers choose this and how can I avoid it?

Comment: That’s pretty much the reason it takes a constructor instead of a value. `defaultdict(list)`, `foo[x].append(y)`, neat. If you want a default value that isn’t inserted, `.get` on a regular dict is a good option a lot of the time. So… “I feel like the purpose of defaultdict is to allow the user to get a default value without putting that key in the dictionary”… well, no, it isn’t, because it very explicitly doesn’t do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not about language design. You can choose not to use `collection.defaultdict`.

You can define your own dictionary that act as you want by defining [`__missing__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__missing__) method:

```py
>>> class MyDefaultDict(dict):
...     def __init__(self, default_factory):
...         self.default_factory = default_factory
...     def __missing__(self, key):
...         # called by dict.__getitem__ when key is not in the dictionary.
...         return self.default_factory()
... 
>>> 
>>> foo = MyDefaultDict(int)
>>> 1 in foo
False
>>> foo[1]
0
>>> 1 in foo
False
```

SIDE NOTE: `defaultdict` is implemented using `__missing__`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot avoid this using `defaultdict` as it's in the core implementation of it:

```
class defaultdict:

    @staticmethod
    def __new__(cls, default_factory=None, **kwargs):
        # Some code (e.g. urllib.urlparse) expects that basic defaultdict
        # functionality will be available to subclasses without them
        # calling __init__().
        self = super(defaultdict, cls).__new__(cls)
        self.d = {}
        return self

    def __init__(self, default_factory=None, **kwargs):
        self.d = kwargs
        self.default_factory = default_factory

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        try:
            return self.d[key]
        except KeyError:
            v = self.__missing__(key)
            self.d[key] = v
            return v

    def __setitem__(self, key, v):
        self.d[key] = v

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        del self.d[key]

    def __contains__(self, key):
        return key in self.d

    def __missing__(self, key):
        if self.default_factory is None:
            raise KeyError(key)
        return self.default_factory()
```

You can see clearly here

```
   def __getitem__(self, key):
        try:
            return self.d[key]
        except KeyError:
            v = self.__missing__(key)
            self.d[key] = v
            return v
```

That after getting a default value for missing key, it registers the key you tried in the dict.

That is really important in a case like having a list map for example:

```
from collections import defaultdict

list_map = defaultdict(list)
list_map['some_key'].append(5)

print(list_map['some_key'])
```

will output:

```
[5]
```

here you can see that I'm trying to get a new key and at the same I want to add a new element to the list referenced by that key, in your proposal that won't be valid since you will return me a default empty list every time that is linked to Nothing.

in your implementation it will output instead

```
[]
```

You could change the implementation if you like, it's a small change but you have to count for the consequences of your change.